# Why am I allowed method access less restrictive than class access?

Tags: swift

Why does this compile?

```
internal class A {

    public func f() {

    }
}
```

I expected f's "public" modifier to be disallowed because its enclosing class is internal.

Comment: I agree this should be an error. Oddly, this isn't covered at all in Apple's "The Swift Programming Language" book under access levels.

Comment: @rmaddy What do you think of my answer?

Comment: I think the quote in your answer applies to a completely different thing than the code in your question. For example, a public function can't return a value with a private type.

Comment: An entity is defined as, "The various aspect of your code that can have access control applied to them." So, a class and a method are both entities. A class is defined in terms of methods. So I think the quote in my answer applies. Its a *guiding principle* after all.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I think you're right. So why do you think it should be an error?

Comment: I don't any more after reading the answer by Hamish.

Answer (score 9):

One motivation for allowing this is mentioned in [SE-0025: Scoped Access Level](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0025-scoped-access-level.md) (emphasis mine):

> The compiler should not warn when a broader level of access control is used within a type with more restrictive access, such as `internal` within a `private` type. **This allows the owner of the type to design the access they would use were they to make the type more widely accessible.** (The members still cannot be accessed outside the enclosing lexical scope because the type itself is still restricted, i.e. outside code will never encounter a value of that type.)

So, although it doesn't change the accessibility of the members, it allows developers to communicate the access level they feel a given member should have if the enclosing type had a broader access level – which could for example be useful for APIs that currently have `internal` types which are planned to be made `public` in a future release.

Comment: Key word is "warn". Even if it warned, I presume it would still compile.

Comment: @IanWarburton Sure, but the motivation for allowing this behaviour is the same regardless of whether you think it should be an error or a warning. I don't see any reason why it *shouldn't* compile – because it doesn't affect the accessibility of the member, as it's still limited by the access level of the enclosing scope. Therefore as there's no change in behaviour, if it were not intended, a warning would be more appropriate than a compiler error IMO.

Comment: The question was why does the code compile, not why doesn't it generate a warning.

Comment: @IanWarburton A motivation for why the code should compile warning-free is surely also a motivation for why that code should compile in the first place? It compiles because "*The members still cannot be accessed outside the enclosing lexical scope because the type itself is still restricted, i.e. outside code will never encounter a value of that type.*" – therefore as there's no change in the accessibility of the members (nothing can break as a result of making that change), there's no reason why it shouldn't compile. Why do you think that it shouldn't compile?

Comment: As I implied in the question, it shouldn't compile because it perhaps contradicts the Guiding Principle of Access Levels. But, as I wrote in my answer, it doesn't.

Comment: @IanWarburton It doesn't contradict the guiding principle of access levels. In your example, the method `f()` has the access level of `internal` (even though it's annotated as `public`) – as it's limited by the access level of the enclosing scope.

Comment: Even if it were public, as the declaration specifies, it still wouldn't contradict it.

Comment: @IanWarburton Oh I think I see what you're saying now. Assuming I understand you correctly, you're saying that "*A class is defined in terms of methods*" and that the guiding principle you quoted in your answer therefore says that a class cannot be defined in terms of methods that have a more restrictive access level (and therefore the inverse must be true). But this is clearly flawed logic as a `public` class *can* (and indeed should be able to) have `private` (more restrictive) methods. To be honest, it's quite ambiguous exactly what the quoted guiding principle is applicable to.

Comment: I interpret it as talking about the types used in a declaration – (e.g the types used in a function cannot have a lower access level than the function itself, or a subclass cannot have a superclass with a more restrictive access level). I don't believe it bears any relevance to the relation between a lexical scope and a declaration in that scope, because as mentioned above, the declaration has its access level limited by the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift reference says under the **Guiding Principle of Access Levels**,

> No entity can be defined in terms of another entity that has a lower
>   (more restrictive) access level.

So, I suppose that doesn't mean that an entity can't be defined in terms of another entity that has a higher access level. In fact, that would surely be necessary.