# public static vs open static vs public class vs open class?

Tags: swift, swift3, scope, overriding

With the introduction of the `open` keyword in Swift 3 suddenly the following are valid scope modifiers for a method: `open static`, `public static`, `open class`, `public class`, but what exactly are their differences? I understand that `public` is meant to be the equivalent of `public final` in Java allowing `open` class methods and variables to be overridden, but then what do `public class func` or `open static func` mean? Are they synonymous to `public static func`? i.e. All 3 implementations would not allow overriding by subclasses? Are there unique advantages to each of the 4 different permutations in specific contexts?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This question is over-complicated because you're comparing the members of the cartesian product of two variables (`open` vs `public` and `static` vs `class`), rather than asking about the two variables separately.

It's not a matter of `open static` vs `public static` vs `open class` vs `public class`, but rather of `open` vs `public` and `static` vs `class`. They're two orthogonal dimensions.

### `open` vs `public`

#### `public`:

Within the module, the `public` access specifier allows access *and* overriding.

From outside the module, the `public` access specifier allows access, *but does not* permit overrides/subclasses.

#### `open`:

Within the module, the `open` access specifier allows access *and* overriding.

From outside the module, the `open` access specifier allows access, *and* permits overrides/subclasses.

### `static` vs `class`

#### `static`:

A `static` member (method or property) is one who is bound to the specific scope (`class`/`struct`/`enum`) it is defined in. It's named such because access to such members is always statically dispatched. This is equivalent to Java's `static`. Objective C has no equivalent to this.

#### `class`:

A `class` member is one who is bound to a class or its subclasses. `class` members can be overridden by subclasses. Because of this, they're dynamically dispatched in the general case, although accesses to `class` members can be devirtualized by the optimizer in some cases. Java has no equivalent to this. This is equivalent to Objective C's class (`+`) methods.

Comment: When would I decide whether to use `public static` vs `open static`?

Comment: @NoodleofDeath I don't think `open static` should be valid, but it is for some reason. I'm not sure it makes sense, as static members can't be overridden

Comment: @Hamish Noted, I've made those changes. Do you have any explanation as to why `open static` is a valid combination?

Comment: @Alexander From what I can tell, the Swift team have always tended on the side of 'no harm in permitting degenerate combinations of access levels' – most notably being the ability to declare members with a higher access level than the type they're defined on, e.g a `public` method in a `private` class. [Their reasoning for *that*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40289745/2976878) was that it allowed programmers to consider and document how the member should be treated if the type was ever promoted to a higher access level...

Comment: ... I guess the same logic also holds for `open static`, for if the member was ever to be made a `class` member, then it's clear that the API also intended for it to be overridable by other modules.

Comment: @Hamish Great find. That's a very interesting point, and I like it. Makes total sense!

Comment: @Hamish I have been coding like that for sometime... good to known I'm not alone :) The only downside I detected, so far, is that it can confuse Swift junior developers.