# Should I use public member of internal type?

Tags: swift

I've been searching over access control guides and tutorials, but couldn't find any information.

Imagine you have some Swift module with class `A` implementation. This class is `internal`. It has some property, let's call it `prop`.

The question is: what changes if I set it's access level from `internal` to `public`?

```
internal class A {

    public var prop: String?
}
```

I saw examples of such code, but don't understand, why. Is it just useful when you decide to make your type `public`, so you don't need to change access level of properties and methods? Or it has some other practical use like giving someone else access while the type is still `internal`?

Comment: Compare [Why am I allowed method access less restrictive than class access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40289745/2976878). There's no difference in access, but it allows you to document what access level you think members should have if the type is ever exposed to a higher access level.

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple doc

> A public variable cannot be defined as having an internal,
>   file-private, or private type, because the type might not be available
>   everywhere that the public variable is used.

More about Internal -

> Internal access enables entities to be used within any source file
>   from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that
>   module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a
>   framework’s internal structure.

So no use of declared public inside internal class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in overall functionality: since your class is `internal`, it cannot be exposed in public members, say `public var propA : A` or `public func f(a:A)` so the fact that its members have `public` visibility makes no difference.

However, by using `public` you avoid repeating yourself: you have already designated the whole class `internal`, so you don't need to designate all its individual members as `internal`.

It also becomes helpful if you decide to convert the class to `public` at some later time, because you change only one `internal` modifier to `public`.