# Open function in a non-open class

Tags: swift, swift5, access-levels

Does it even make sense?
We will not have a chance to override an open function in a class which can't be subclassed (by the way, by default class is internal, not public, right?)
If it doesn't make sense, why doesn't Xcode show any warnings?

Comment: Note that you can also make methods in a `private` class to be `public`. The more general question is, why can class members be more accessible than the class?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289745/why-am-i-allowed-method-access-less-restrictive-than-class-access